# Perl GnuPG returns NO_SECKEY even with a specified password

Tags: perl, gnupg

I'm doing a small program, a part of which has to decipher gpg messages that are transmitted between two pcs. Unfortunately the perl GnuPG library returns:

> GnuPG::abort_gnupg(GnuPG=HASH(0x1ddba80), "Protocol error: expected NEED_PASSPHRASE.* got NO_SECKEY\x{a}")

when I run this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use GnuPG;

my ($gpg, $msg, $dec, $pwd, $tfile);

$gpg = new GnuPG ( gnupg_path => "/usr/bin/gpg",);
$pwd = "pwd";     #
$msg = "message"; #
$tfile = "/tmp/local_scripts/temp.txt";

chomp $msg;
open (my $fh, ">", $tfile) or die "Cannot open temporary file: $!";
print $fh $msg;
close ($fh);

$gpg->decrypt
(
    symmetric => 1,
    ciphertext => $tfile,
    passphrase => $pwd,
    output => $dec,
);

print $dec;
```

Am I even using the right library to do this, or do I have to turn to Crypto::GnuPG (which, when tested, gave me "Decryption failed: Can't find a secret key to decrypt message", even with a specified password...) I'm lost really

Answer (score 1):

Appears that in order to get it running, you must fully specify the locations of the GnuPG homedir, options file & gpg_path whenever you're calling the GnuPG constructor:

> $gpg = new GnuPG ( gnupg_path => "/usr/bin/gpg", homedir => "/home/your_username/.gnupg/", options => "/home/your_username/.gnupg/gpg.conf");

*(Tested on Debian 8)*